# Get all columns from Excel except selected

Tags: excel, automated-tests, ado, qtp, hp-uft

I have excel files converted to txt. In some files, some columns are skipped. That is controlled by database:

```
file   | remove_column
=======+===============
file1  | CASE NOTE
-------+---------------
file2  | Description
-------+---------------
file3  | Item | Address
```

Remove_Column has the header (1st row). If several columns should be skipped, they are delimited with '|'

I have to compare converted txt file with original excel file if they match. How can I read all columns except those showed in DB table?

I am using UFT 12.5. Reading Excel through Excel.Application or ADO.
Thnx)

**UPD:** Code I use:

I have columns hard-coded:

```
Select Case OrigFileName 'file names come from database
    Case "Fees mm-yy.xls"
        ColumnNames = Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13", ",")
    Case "Exp mm-yy.xls"
        ColumnNames = Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20", ",")
End Select
```

But there are 50 files, and the business might ask to remove or to add back any columns; also, new files are coming...(((

```
Dim fsox : Set fsox = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim TargFileRead : Set TargFileRead = fsox.OpenTextFile(targetFile)
Dim OrgExcel : Set OrgExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
OrgExcel.Workbooks.Open(originalfile)
Set vSheet = OrgExcel.WorkSheets(TabUse) 'excel sheet name, comes from database
print  vSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For rc = 1 To vSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For coc = 0 To UBound(ColumnNames) 'column names hard-coded
    cc = cInt(ColumnNames(coc))
    vtext = vSheet.cells(rc,cc)
    If NOT(vtext=ChrW(9)) Then
        If vstring="" Then
            vstring=vtext
        Else
            vstring = vstring&vbTab&vtext
        End If
    End If
    If len(vstring)>0 Then
        TargFileText = TargFileRead.ReadLine
        Do 
            If Left(TargFileText, 1)=ChrW(9) Then
                TargFileText = MID(TargFileText, 2)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        Do 
            If RIGHT(TargFileText, 1)=ChrW(9) Then
            TargFileText= mid(TargFileText,1,len(TargFileText)-1)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        TargFileStr = Trim(TargFileText)

        If trim(vstring) = trim(TargFileStr) Then
'           print "match"
            Else
            print "-=Not Match=-"&VBNewLine&"txt:::"&trim(TargFileStr)&VBNewLine&"xls:::"&trim(vstring)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Do you have code for reading all the columns, but don't know how to skip certain columns? If so, can you please provide your code.

Comment: oh, yes, I forgot... Now the question is updated.

Comment: Just to clarify: the goal is to replace the ColumnNumbers with an algorithm reading all columns except those that have the String in your table for the worksheet in row 1, right?

Comment: @JensS, absolutely right.

Comment: Great; I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to replace the Switch statement with a function call that gives you the relevant columns for the sheet as an array. The logic which column is allowed is then put in another function. That should make the logic more flexible than fixed columns.

```
Function getColumns(OrigFileName as String) As String()
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim ColumnNumbers As String
    lastCol = Sheets(OrigFileName).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For col = 1 To lastCol
        If isColumnAllowed(OrigFileName, Sheets(OrigFileName).Cells(1, col)) Then
            ColumnNumbers = ColumnNumbers & IIf(Len(ColumnNumbers) = 0, "", ",") & col
        End If
    Next

    getColumns = Split(ColumnNumbers, ",")
End Function

Function isColumnAllowed(ByVal OrigFileName As String, columnName As String) As Boolean
    Select Case OrigFileName
        Case "file1"
            Forbidden = Split("CASE NOTE", "/")
        Case "file2"
            Forbidden = Split("Description", "/")
        Case "file3"
            Forbidden = Split("Item/ Address", "/")
    End Select

    isColumnAllowed = (UBound(Filter(Forbidden, columnName)) = -1)
End Function
```

Comment: It works good for VB, thanks!
I am using UFT, and have to make some modifications, because the code directly doesn't work there. Later will post my "edition".

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now and is working:

```
If LEN(ColumnToRemove)>0 Then
    ColumnToRemoveCol = split(ColumnToRemove, "|") 'set collection of header strings to skip column
    For L = 1 To vSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For x = 0 to UBound(ColumnToRemoveCol)
        AddCol = 0 'ColumnToRemoveCol can have more than 1 item, that may cause any column to be added more than once; we will use the true/false logic via 0 and 1 to avoid that doubling
            If vSheet.cells(1, l)=ColumnToRemoveCol(x) Then
                AddCol = AddCol + 1
            End If
        Next
        If AddCol =0 Then ColumnNumbers = ColumnNumbers&","&L
    Next
Else
    For L = 1 To vSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ColumnNumbers = ColumnNumbers&","&L
    Next
End If
If LEFT(ColumnNumbers, 1)="," Then ColumnNumbers=MID(ColumnNumbers, 2)
If RIGHT(ColumnNumbers, 1)="," Then ColumnNumbers=MID(ColumnNumbers, 1, LEN(ColumnNumbers)-1)
```

Printing the columns for first excel file in my case gives the next line:

> ColumnNumbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,17

Further usage:

```
getColumns = Split(ColumnNumbers, ",")
For rc = 1 To vSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For coc = 0 To UBound(getColumns)
        cc = cInt(getColumns(coc))
        vtext = vSheet.cells(rc,cc)
.....
    Next
Next
```